# Chrome update forcing darkmode on websites

Tags: html, css, windows, google-chrome, darkmode

I was wondering if any of you on windows 11 (with dark theme on windows) with google chrome had some issues about Chrome forcing darkmode on every website. Because since few hours all my website are "dark" with just a basic swap from balck to white done by Chrome.

When I diseable dark theme of W11 it does solve the problem, and on other browsers it works as well. So it's all about Chrome and the new update.

Is there a way to diseable this new feature when coding a new website because this is a serious problem if some clients are in this case ? And i wonder if some of you recreate this bug ?

Comment: I am having the same issue, some sites are just not working right with dark mode, I installed a dark mode extension in chrome to "help" fix some of those issues for now. Dark mode chrome extension I am using: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-mode/dmghijelimhndkbmpgbldicpogfkceaj/related

Comment: There's a whole article about this issue (first link on google). Can you please check it and report what worked for you by answering to your post? https://windowsreport.com/dark-mode-chrome-turn-off/

Comment: That article does not work, not if you want to keep dark mode on windows (and apps) but have chrome in light mode... Also the disable Dark Mode code in the exe path does not work anymore, neither do the chrome flags.

Comment: Well as @ShadowMare said from now on you just have ton remove Adobe Acrobat extension and everything work smoothly

Comment: Looks like acrobat plugin has been updated so it is not breaking dark mode anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely remove the Adobe Acrobat Extension for now from your browser. This seems to cause the issue.

Comment: Perfect solution, kinda weird hope they'll fix it later, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just update the adobe acrobat extension, it started working now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

ShadowMare answer did fix that issue perfectly by removing Adobe Acrobat Extension then everything will be fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).