# Google Chrome Profile's Background Color Turned Black

Tags: google-chrome

I am having a problem with google chrome - something like this: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAJrh.png)
What I have tried -

> Reinstalling Chrome,
> Uninstalling plugins,
> restarting chrome,
> Disabling forced colors through chrome://flags, Removing profiles and adding new ones, and searching online

It also happens with other websites e.g. google classroom and google docs: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzNmF.png)

I believe it is something dealing with the body element color, could someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I found a different question where someone has found the solution:
[Chrome update forcing darkmode on websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253378/chrome-update-forcing-darkmode-on-websites)

[ShadowMare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578502/shadowmare)'s solution worked for me:

"Completely remove the Adobe Acrobat Extension for now from your browser. This seems to cause the issue."
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/71254463/14017735)